# UML : Process and Activity diagram

Tags: uml

Can I use bidirectional arrows in Process/Activity UML diagram? Any example?
I am preparing a process diagram with swimlanes. what I encountered that many processes are cross referencing across the swim lanes. Not a good as-is design. Just want to know is it ok to use bidirectional arrows to represent such process diagram? What are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

The UML specs is hard to digest here. Activities/actions are connected with `ControlFlow`s (see p. 418 of the specs). A `ControlFlow` itself is an `ActivityEdge` (see p. 411):

> An ActivityEdge is an abstract class for directed connections between two ActivityNodes.

There is no constraint (I could find) that forbids bi-directional use. All examples of `ControlFlow`s are just directed with single arrow, though.

Using bi-directional flows will not let you specify guards/behavior easily as you can not detect which is for which direction. But if you have unconditional flow it should just be fine.

**Edit** On p. 22 it is stated

> A DirectedRelationship represents a Relationship between a collection of source model elements and a collection of target model elements. A DirectedRelationship is said to be directed from the source elements to the target elements.

`DirectedRelationship` inherits from `Relationship` which inherits from `Element`. `ActivityEdge`in contrast inherits from `RedefinableElement` <- `NamedElement` <- `Element`. Likely they "mean" that `ControlFlow` has to be directed from source to target. But in fact it's not defined.

**tl;dr** It's up to you if you use only uni-directional connectors as shown in examples in the spec. But per definition it's not defined (sic!) and bi-directional connectors do not violate the specs.

Comment: True, I couldn't find bi-directional Activity examples. Thought of "am I doing something wrong?". Also it is a pain to define relationships in a standard UML guidelines. I am writing workflows on the basis of this and it is getting complex due such cross referencing between processes.

Comment: I think **directed** means **in one direction** and therefore implies that bi-directional control flows are not valid.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Good hint. I fostered the specs and it's probably a flaw in the specs. I'm tired of reporting bugs that only end up in lists (like the glossary I asked for years ago which would have helped here).

Comment: I think you'd do better to place a control flow joining A to B, and then another control flow joining B to A, both of which you can then apply a guard to if necessary. I would avoid bi-directional as readers (probably) won't have a clue what you mean.

Comment: @muszeo This is what the OP wants to avoid (probably to ease drawing work?).